# is these two dictonary statments are same while looping it in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I read that my_dict.keys() returns the dynamic view to iterate over the dictionary. I usually iterate the dictionary without the keys() function.

So my question is, are below two code blokes are same? if not, what performance differences do these two have (which one is more optimized)

```
# without keys() function
my_dict = {'key1' : 'value1',"key2" : "value2"}

for key in my_dict:
  print("current key is",key)
```

```
# withkeys() function
my_dict = {'key1' : 'value1',"key2" : "value2"}

for key in my_dict.keys():
  print("current key is",key)
```

Note: I usually use python version 3.7+ so if there's any version-wise implementation difference, kindly attach resources that I can refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `for key in my_dict` is slightly faster... try:

```
from time import time

my_dict = {'key1' : 'value1',"key2" : "value2"}

start = time()
for _ in range(1000000):
    for key in my_dict:
      a = key
print(time() - start)


my_dict = {'key1' : 'value1',"key2" : "value2"}

start = time()
for _ in range(1000000):
    for key in my_dict.keys():
      a = key
print(time() - start)

# 0.28826069831848145
# 0.3530569076538086
```

Which is what I'd expect because `for key in my_dict.keys():` involves one more method call.

---

Edit: it appears I've used a crude method (`time.time()`) for the measurements as @ShadowRanger pointed out. See his insightful answer and comments. Also, apologies for referring to an outdated documentation.

A better approach would be using `timeit` which would show the results in both cases are almost identical as pointed out in @ShadowRanger's answer, confirming other observations in the comments.

```
from timeit import repeat

repeat(setup="my_dict = {i : 'value' for i in range(1000)}", stmt="""
for _ in range(100):
    for key in my_dict.keys():
      a = key
""", number=1000
)

repeat(setup="my_dict = {i : 'value' for i in range(1000)}", stmt="""
for _ in range(100):
    for key in my_dict:
      a = key
""", number=1000
)

"""
[2.141656800000419,
 2.098019299999578,
 2.0064776999997775,
 1.9754404000004797,
 2.020252399999663]

[1.9935685999998896,
 2.021206500000517,
 2.028992300000027,
 2.026352799999586,
 2.0209632999994938]
"""
```

Comment: Test with a larger dictionary...

Comment: I also tested this. I got the same result that for key in my_dict is faster... Any idea why is this?

Comment: `iter(my_dict)` and `iter(my_dict.keys())` both return an instance of `dict_keyiterator`, but the second one involves an extra call to the `keys` method that the first does not.

Comment: good point @MadPhysicist, for `my_dict = {i : 'value' for i in range(10000)}` the speeds are equal (6.5 secs for 10.000 repetition in both cases). I wonder why...

Comment: @isCzech i tested with big dict, now the .keys() is faster which doesn't make sense if both were implimented the same way and only delay was function call.

Comment: @SahilLohiya, precisely, I've just tried a dictionary with 100.000 items and 1000 repetitions and .keys() version is faster, so it must be a bit more complicated. My hypothesis: in a small dictionary the cost of access is very small and the extra method call in my_dict.keys() plays a visible role, while in a big dictionary the cost of access is higher (because of hashing collisions) and the cost of the extra method call becomes negligible. That wouldn't explain why .keys() version may be even faster, however. So my suspicion is the iterators in the for loop are a different in the two versions.

Comment: @isCzech yes the confusion is I checked the assembly code with a library called dis.dis 
 .there also keys() function looks slower than the simple implementation. but in practice, it is totally different

Comment: from a documentation I'd say `for key in my_dict` uses `iterkeys` iterator while `for key in my_dict.keys()` first creates a copy of the dictionary’s list of keys and then uses an iterator over this copy which in general will be different and possibly a bit faster. (check this https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/)

Comment: @isCzech: That reference is out-dated/incorrect; in Python 2 it eagerly created a `list` of keys, but in Python 3 it's a live view of the underlying `dict`'s keys (it iterates the `dict` itself, no copies involved, just a cheap wrapper view).

Comment: Also, using plain `time` for your test is a terrible test metric. Learn the `timeit` module. And make sure your computer has all power-saving measures disabled; if you don't, the second loop is likely to run faster simply because the processor is already clocked up (due to heavy usage) on beginning the loop.

Comment: @ShadowRanger This solves many of my doubts, I ran code with a minute gap(so there's no issue of cpu clocked up) in google colab with %%time magic function,  it gave almost identical results.

Answer (score 3):

The two code blocks are the same, the only difference is that calling `.keys()` creates a temporary keys view object that is thrown away almost immediately (when the implicit call to `iter` that begins the `for` loop creates a `dict_keyiterator` object that references the underlying `dict`). The cost of creating a keys view is pretty small, so for large `dict`s, the cost is irrelevant.

Proving they're the same (run on 3.10.8):

```
>>> print(type(iter({})))
<class 'dict_keyiterator'>

>>> print(type(iter({}.keys())))
<class 'dict_keyiterator'>
```

On Python 2, there was a big difference (`.keys()` would eagerly shallow copy the keys to a new `list`), but in Python 3, `.keys()` is just wasting a tiny fixed amount of work making the keys view up front, and otherwise the rest of the loop behaves & performs *identically*.